# A more complex Island & Gaps problem in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, gaps-and-islands

First of all i would like to apologize if this was already discussed, but after 4 hours of searching I wasn't able to find anything which could help me with my problem.

This is the scenario: there are towers where different clients can have different equipment mounted at different heights on that tower (like the tower in telecom).

[image: example]

These are the facts:

- the tower has 4 sides and the equipment can be mounted (for the same height) only on 2 opposite sides. So we cannot have equipment mounted (at the same height) on 3 different sides of the tower not on 2 sides which are near. I hope I'm explaining ok.
- each client has its own range from the total height of an tower.

The requirement is to determine what would be the availability for each client in that tower. If an client has an equipment mounted only on one side, it would be considered Partial Available; if has no equipment at all it would be considered Available. If the customer has equipment mounted on bot opposite sides of the tower, that height it will be considered not available.

[image: example]

These would be the data we are working on:

```
create table tower_test
(Tower_Number        VARCHAR2(12),
 Tower_Side          VARCHAR2(1),
 Tower_Height        NUMBER,
 Tower_Height_Um     VARCHAR2(1) default 'm',
 Client              VARCHAR2(25),
 Client_Start_Height NUMBER,
 Range_From          NUMBER,
 Range_To            NUMBER);
 
-- No Client

-- Side A
-- Client 1 
INSERT INTO tower_test (Tower_Number, Tower_Side, Tower_Height, Client, Client_Start_Height, Range_From, Range_To) VALUES ('123456_TWR1', 'A', 50, 'Client_1', 12, 17, 18);
INSERT INTO tower_test (Tower_Number, Tower_Side, Tower_Height, Client, Client_Start_Height, Range_From, Range_To) VALUES ('123456_TWR1', 'A', 50, 'Client_1', 12, 22, 23);
-- Client 2
INSERT INTO tower_test (Tower_Number, Tower_Side, Tower_Height, Client, Client_Start_Height, Range_From, Range_To) VALUES ('123456_TWR1', 'A', 50, 'Client_2', 24, 35, 36);
-- Client 3
INSERT INTO tower_test (Tower_Number, Tower_Side, Tower_Height, Client, Client_Start_Height, Range_From, Range_To) VALUES ('123456_TWR1', 'A', 50, 'Client_3', 40, 40, 41);
INSERT INTO tower_test (Tower_Number, Tower_Side, Tower_Height, Client, Client_Start_Height, Range_From, Range_To) VALUES ('123456_TWR1', 'A', 50, 'Client_3', 40, 47, 48);

-- Side B
-- Client 1
INSERT INTO tower_test (Tower_Number, Tower_Side, Tower_Height, Client, Client_Start_Height, Range_From, Range_To) VALUES ('123456_TWR1', 'B', 50, 'Client_1', 12, 13, 14);
INSERT INTO tower_test (Tower_Number, Tower_Side, Tower_Height, Client, Client_Start_Height, Range_From, Range_To) VALUES ('123456_TWR1', 'B', 50, 'Client_1', 12, 19, 20);
-- Client 2
INSERT INTO tower_test (Tower_Number, Tower_Side, Tower_Height, Client, Client_Start_Height, Range_From, Range_To) VALUES ('123456_TWR1', 'B', 50, 'Client_2', 24, 31, 32);
INSERT INTO tower_test (Tower_Number, Tower_Side, Tower_Height, Client, Client_Start_Height, Range_From, Range_To) VALUES ('123456_TWR1', 'B', 50, 'Client_2', 24, 37, 38);
-- Client 3
INSERT INTO tower_test (Tower_Number, Tower_Side, Tower_Height, Client, Client_Start_Height, Range_From, Range_To) VALUES ('123456_TWR1', 'B', 50, 'Client_3', 40, 43, 44);
INSERT INTO tower_test (Tower_Number, Tower_Side, Tower_Height, Client, Client_Start_Height, Range_From, Range_To) VALUES ('123456_TWR1', 'B', 50, 'Client_3', 40, 46, 47);

-- Side C
-- Client 1 
INSERT INTO tower_test (Tower_Number, Tower_Side, Tower_Height, Client, Client_Start_Height, Range_From, Range_To) VALUES ('123456_TWR1', 'C', 50, 'Client_1', 12, 17, 18);
INSERT INTO tower_test (Tower_Number, Tower_Side, Tower_Height, Client, Client_Start_Height, Range_From, Range_To) VALUES ('123456_TWR1', 'C', 50, 'Client_1', 12, 22, 23);
-- Client 2
INSERT INTO tower_test (Tower_Number, Tower_Side, Tower_Height, Client, Client_Start_Height, Range_From, Range_To) VALUES ('123456_TWR1', 'C', 50, 'Client_2', 24, 28, 29);
-- Client 3
INSERT INTO tower_test (Tower_Number, Tower_Side, Tower_Height, Client, Client_Start_Height, Range_From, Range_To) VALUES ('123456_TWR1', 'C', 50, 'Client_3', 40, 40, 41);
INSERT INTO tower_test (Tower_Number, Tower_Side, Tower_Height, Client, Client_Start_Height, Range_From, Range_To) VALUES ('123456_TWR1', 'C', 50, 'Client_3', 40, 47, 48);

-- Side D
-- Client 1
INSERT INTO tower_test (Tower_Number, Tower_Side, Tower_Height, Client, Client_Start_Height, Range_From, Range_To) VALUES ('123456_TWR1', 'D', 50, 'Client_1', 12, 19, 20);
-- Client 2
INSERT INTO tower_test (Tower_Number, Tower_Side, Tower_Height, Client, Client_Start_Height, Range_From, Range_To) VALUES ('123456_TWR1', 'D', 50, 'Client_2', 24, 31, 32);
INSERT INTO tower_test (Tower_Number, Tower_Side, Tower_Height, Client, Client_Start_Height, Range_From, Range_To) VALUES ('123456_TWR1', 'D', 50, 'Client_2', 24, 37, 38);
-- Client 3
INSERT INTO tower_test (Tower_Number, Tower_Side, Tower_Height, Client, Client_Start_Height, Range_From, Range_To) VALUES ('123456_TWR1', 'D', 50, 'Client_3', 40, 46, 47);

COMMIT;

SELECT * FROM tower_test;
```

So, starting from this set of data:

[image: example]

I would need this format:

[image: example]

Is there any way to get that in Oracle SQL using Gap & Island approach? If yes, can you explain me how to achieve it?

Thanks!

Comment: [Edit] the question and tag the DBMS you're using and its version.

Comment: I believe *varchar2* indicates Oracle

Comment: The `TOWER_NUMBER`, `TOWER_SIDE`, `TOWER_HEIGHT`, and `TOWER_HEIGHT_UM` columns do not appear to be part of the question.  Is that correct?

Comment: Can you describe the `client_1` rows of the output?  Why isn't the third row of the output `client_1`, `P`, `13`, `14`?

Comment: The order of the columns in the output is not that important. What I need is to be able to get continuous gap between occupied spaces as "availability", as I have described in my initial post. This is part of an BI project, so I should be able to display these "availability" and "partial availability" along with all the other information, like I suggested in my final output.
BTW, in the output, in the Avlblt_Type column, T stands for "Availability" and P for "Partial Availability"

Comment: I have modified my initial post and used images for better understanding (I wasn't able to do so initially because it was my first post)

Comment: Please describe the meaning of all the columns in the data model. Currently it is not clear what is the purpose of `Client_Start_Height` and which columns indicate mounted aquipment.

Comment: In my example: If the tower has 50 m total height, first 11 m are free (meaning that no client use that portion). Client 1 rent the portion between 12 m and 23 m, Client 2 has from 24 m to 29 m and the Client 3 has from 40 m to 50 m. So, that column (Client_Start_Height) indicates the height from which the client "own" its portion of the tower. Maybe it should be Client_Start_Height and Client_End_Height, but this can be easily deducted only from Client_Start_Height - the Client "own" everything from that point until the other client Client_Start_Height - if any...

Comment: Range_From and Range_To indicates that an equipment is mounted on that height/side (from ... to ... height). So, if we have Range_From & Range_To => we have an equipment. If not, that portion of the tower is free.

Comment: Why does the data have client_1's start height as 12 and ranges from 12 to 23, but the output has lowest range starting at 11 and highest ending at 22? I'm struggling to see quite how the numbers in the results relate to the source data - but I'm not sure if that's because they don't match, or because I don't understand your logic. Please edit your question to explain fully, rather than putting a lot of information in comments.

Comment: Can the same client have multiple ranges at the same tower? Output data looks inconsistent. In the output 11 is used as a starting range for `Client_1`, but it is the upper boundary for `No client`. Then for `Client_1` you have no intersection (the "next" row starts at previous `range_to` + 1. But for `Client_2` it also contains intersections. The range from 18 to 20 is not classified at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would probably be easier if you had your data in third normal form and the data in four tables:

```
tower (tower_number, tower_height, tower_height_um)
tower_sides (tower_number, tower_side)
tower_client (tower_number, client, client_start_height, client_end_height)
tower_equipment(tower, tower_side, client, range_from, range_to)
```

However, it is possible to split it into those components from your table and use:

```sql
SELECT tower_number,
       tower_height,
       tower_height_um,
       client,
       CASE availability
       WHEN 0 THEN 'T'
       WHEN 1 THEN 'P'
       END AS availability,
       range_from,
       range_to
FROM   (
SELECT h.tower_number,
       MAX(h.tower_height) AS tower_height,
       MAX(h.tower_height_um) AS tower_height_um,
       h.height,
       MAX(ch.client) AS client,
       COUNT(t.tower_side) AS availability
FROM   (
         -- Generate all the heights and sides
         WITH heights (tower_number, tower_side, height, tower_height, tower_height_um) AS (
           SELECT tower_number,
                  tower_side,
                  0,
                  MAX(tower_height),
                  MAX(tower_height_um) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY tower_height)
           FROM   tower_test
           GROUP BY tower_number, tower_side
         UNION ALL
           SELECT tower_number,
                  tower_side,
                  height + 1,
                  tower_height,
                  tower_height_um
           FROM   heights
           WHERE  height < tower_height
         )
         SELECT * FROM heights
       ) h
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (
         -- Include the client heights
         SELECT *
         FROM   (
           SELECT DISTINCT
                  tower_number,
                  client,
                  client_start_height AS start_height,
                  LEAD(client_start_height - 1, 1, tower_height) OVER (
                    PARTITION BY tower_number
                    ORDER BY client_start_height, range_to
                  ) AS end_height
           FROM   tower_test
         )
         WHERE  start_height < end_height
       ) ch
       ON (    h.tower_number = ch.tower_number
           AND h.height BETWEEN ch.start_height AND ch.end_height)
       -- Include the equipment ranges
       LEFT OUTER JOIN tower_test t
       ON (    t.tower_number = h.tower_number
           AND t.tower_side = h.tower_side
           AND h.height BETWEEN t.range_from AND t.range_to)
GROUP BY
      h.tower_number,
      h.height
)
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY tower_number
  ORDER BY height
  MEASURES
    FIRST(tower_height) AS tower_height,
    FIRST(tower_height_um) AS tower_height_um,
    FIRST(client) AS client,
    FIRST(availability) AS availability,
    FIRST(height) AS range_from,
    LAST(height) AS range_to
  ONE ROW PER MATCH
  PATTERN (client_available+)
  DEFINE 
    client_available
      AS (FIRST(client) = client OR FIRST(client) IS NULL AND client IS NULL)
      AND FIRST(availability) = availability
)
WHERE availability < 2
```

Which, for your sample data, outputs:

> | TOWER_NUMBER | TOWER_HEIGHT | TOWER_HEIGHT_UM | CLIENT | AVAILABILITY | RANGE_FROM | RANGE_TO |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 123456_TWR1 | 50 | m | *null* | T | 0 | 11 |
> | 123456_TWR1 | 50 | m | Client_1 | T | 12 | 12 |
> | 123456_TWR1 | 50 | m | Client_1 | P | 13 | 14 |
> | 123456_TWR1 | 50 | m | Client_1 | T | 15 | 16 |
> | 123456_TWR1 | 50 | m | Client_1 | T | 21 | 21 |
> | 123456_TWR1 | 50 | m | Client_2 | T | 24 | 27 |
> | 123456_TWR1 | 50 | m | Client_2 | P | 28 | 29 |
> | 123456_TWR1 | 50 | m | Client_2 | T | 30 | 30 |
> | 123456_TWR1 | 50 | m | Client_2 | T | 33 | 34 |
> | 123456_TWR1 | 50 | m | Client_2 | P | 35 | 36 |
> | 123456_TWR1 | 50 | m | Client_2 | T | 39 | 39 |
> | 123456_TWR1 | 50 | m | Client_3 | T | 42 | 42 |
> | 123456_TWR1 | 50 | m | Client_3 | P | 43 | 44 |
> | 123456_TWR1 | 50 | m | Client_3 | T | 45 | 45 |
> | 123456_TWR1 | 50 | m | Client_3 | T | 49 | 50 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=f3774644ac1d3612728617402d5b61fa)*

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
Unfortunately, data are pulled from an OLTP system directly, no transformation involved. And, on top of that, I'm not allowed to create & use views or materialized views.
I could be able though to model somehow into my ODI mapping process so I can load data into those 4 tables you were mentioned and to load data into my final tables using the SQL.

What would be the query if I would have those 4 tables in place?

Comment: @Mihai 3NF version is at the end of [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=061e2b5f0c12db1513f055046ce65086). (As an aside: In the 3NF tables, the `client` column may or may-not want to be in the `tower_equipment` table; its not needed for this query and it can be implicitly calculated from the `tower_client` table but it may be useful to enforce constraints.)

Comment: Thanks mate! I found the other version in that fiddle. I believe I would use any of these 2 version directly in ODI using custom template.

Have a nice day!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that fills up the gaps in the ranges.

It's not exactly as the expected results.
F.e. the gaps get an 'A' code for available.
But it'll be something for you to start with.

The first CTE flattens the data, and gets counts for the tower sides.
The second CTE adds the gaps.

> ```
> WITH CTE1_FLATTEND AS 
> (
>     SELECT 
>       Tower_Number
>     , Client
>     , Client_Start_Height
>     , Range_From
>     , Range_To
>     , COUNT(DISTINCT
>             CASE
>             WHEN Tower_Side IN ('A','C')
>             THEN Tower_Side
>             END) AS Total_AC
>     , COUNT(DISTINCT
>             CASE
>             WHEN Tower_Side IN ('B','D')
>             THEN Tower_Side
>             END) AS Total_BD
>     , COUNT(DISTINCT Tower_Side) AS Total_ABCD
>     , MAX(Tower_Height) AS Tower_Height
>     , MAX(Tower_Height_Um) AS Tower_Height_Um
>     FROM tower_test
>     GROUP BY
>       Tower_Number
>     , Client
>     , Client_Start_Height
>     , Range_From
>     , Range_To
> )
> , CTE2_GAPS_ADDED AS
> (
>     SELECT
>       Tower_Number
>     , Client
>     , Client_Start_Height
>     , Client_Start_Height AS Next_Client_Start_Height
>     , COALESCE(LAG(Range_To) 
>         OVER (PARTITION BY Tower_Number, Client_Start_Height
>               ORDER BY Range_From)+1, Client_Start_Height) AS Range_From
>     , Range_From-1 AS Range_To
>     , 'A' AS Avlblt_Type -- Available Gap
>     , Tower_Height
>     , Tower_Height_Um
>     FROM CTE1_FLATTEND
>    
>     UNION
>
>     SELECT
>       Tower_Number
>     , Client
>     , Client_Start_Height
>     , COALESCE(LEAD(Client_Start_Height) 
>         OVER (PARTITION BY Tower_Number
>               ORDER BY Range_From), Client_Start_Height) AS Next_Client_Start_Height
>     , Range_To+1 AS Range_From
>     , COALESCE(LEAD(Range_From) 
>         OVER (PARTITION BY Tower_Number
>               ORDER BY Range_From)-1, Tower_Height) AS Range_To
>     , 'A' AS Avlblt_Type -- Available Gap
>     , Tower_Height
>     , Tower_Height_Um
>     FROM CTE1_FLATTEND
>    
>     UNION ALL
>     
>     SELECT
>       Tower_Number
>     , Client
>     , Client_Start_Height
>     , Client_Start_Height AS Next_Client_Start_Height
>     , Range_From
>     , Range_To
>     , CASE
>       WHEN Total_ABCD = 1 THEN 'P' -- Partial
>       WHEN Total_ABCD > 2 THEN 'F' -- Fault
>       WHEN Total_AC = 2   THEN 'T' -- Taken A C
>       WHEN Total_BD = 2   THEN 'T' -- Taken B D
>       ELSE 'E' -- Exception
>       END AS Avlblt_Type
>     , Tower_Height
>     , Tower_Height_Um
>     FROM CTE1_FLATTEND
>     
>     UNION ALL
>     
>     SELECT
>       Tower_Number
>     , 'No Client' AS Client
>     , 1 AS Client_Start_Height
>     , 0 AS Next_Client_Start_Height
>     , 0 AS Range_From
>     , MIN(Client_Start_Height)-1 AS Range_To
>     , 'T' AS Avlblt_Type
>     , Tower_Height
>     , Tower_Height_Um
>     FROM CTE1_FLATTEND
>     GROUP BY 
>       Tower_Number
>     , Tower_Height
>     , Tower_Height_Um
> ) 
> SELECT 
>   Tower_Number
> , Tower_Height
> , Tower_Height_Um
> , Client
> , Avlblt_Type
> , Range_From
> , Range_To
> --, Client_Start_Height
> --, Next_Client_Start_Height
> FROM CTE2_GAPS_ADDED
> WHERE Range_From <= Range_To
>   AND NOT (Client_Start_Height < Next_Client_Start_Height
>            AND Range_From >= Next_Client_Start_Height)
> ORDER BY Tower_Number, Range_From;
> ```

> ```
> TOWER_NUMBER | TOWER_HEIGHT | TOWER_HEIGHT_UM | CLIENT    | AVLBLT_TYPE | RANGE_FROM | RANGE_TO
> :----------- | -----------: | :-------------- | :-------- | :---------- | ---------: | -------:
> 123456_TWR1  |           50 | m               | No Client | T           |          0 |       11
> 123456_TWR1  |           50 | m               | Client_1  | A           |         12 |       12
> 123456_TWR1  |           50 | m               | Client_1  | P           |         13 |       14
> 123456_TWR1  |           50 | m               | Client_1  | A           |         15 |       16
> 123456_TWR1  |           50 | m               | Client_1  | T           |         17 |       18
> 123456_TWR1  |           50 | m               | Client_1  | T           |         19 |       20
> 123456_TWR1  |           50 | m               | Client_1  | A           |         21 |       21
> 123456_TWR1  |           50 | m               | Client_1  | T           |         22 |       23
> 123456_TWR1  |           50 | m               | Client_2  | A           |         24 |       27
> 123456_TWR1  |           50 | m               | Client_2  | P           |         28 |       29
> 123456_TWR1  |           50 | m               | Client_2  | A           |         30 |       30
> 123456_TWR1  |           50 | m               | Client_2  | T           |         31 |       32
> 123456_TWR1  |           50 | m               | Client_2  | A           |         33 |       34
> 123456_TWR1  |           50 | m               | Client_2  | P           |         35 |       36
> 123456_TWR1  |           50 | m               | Client_2  | T           |         37 |       38
> 123456_TWR1  |           50 | m               | Client_2  | A           |         39 |       39
> 123456_TWR1  |           50 | m               | Client_3  | T           |         40 |       41
> 123456_TWR1  |           50 | m               | Client_3  | A           |         42 |       42
> 123456_TWR1  |           50 | m               | Client_3  | P           |         43 |       44
> 123456_TWR1  |           50 | m               | Client_3  | A           |         45 |       45
> 123456_TWR1  |           50 | m               | Client_3  | T           |         46 |       47
> 123456_TWR1  |           50 | m               | Client_3  | T           |         47 |       48
> 123456_TWR1  |           50 | m               | Client_3  | A           |         49 |       50
> ```

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2f1afa6b6a01b8a57e8b2449ffaa561d)*

The second CTE uses the first CTE a lot.
To improve performance, you could fill a temp table with the query from the first.
Then use the temp table in the CTE with the unions.

Comment: Thanks man! Very useful things!